# How to set the height equal to width dynamically using css?

Tags: css, height

For example, for a div with classname icon, after setting the width as 15%, how to set the height appropriately to make this div container as a square?

```
.icon {
    width: 15%; 
}
```

I've tried the aspect-ratio while seems it not work, is there any easy and straightforward way to do it?

Comment: aspect-ratio: 1;